# Left-align one element and center-align another, but have centered element pushed by left element

Tags: html, css, positioning, flexbox

I am currently using flex and I assume it is necessary, but I am open to all CSS solutions.

I have a bar with some elements on the left. This is done with `flex: 0 0 auto;` on this element group and `flex: 1 1 auto;` on an empty element after it.

I need to put another set of elements in the center of this bar (not the center of the remaining space). If the first set of elements weren't there, I could do `flex: 1 1 auto` on the left and right of the centered element with `flex: 0 0 auto;`.

But now I need to combine these so the left element stays on the left and the middle element stays in the middle, but I also need the left element to push the middle element to the right (therefore making it no longer centered) if they touch.

Edit: I should mention that the widths of both elements are dynamic. I do know heights, but it would be better not to need them.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: would be nice if you shared the relevant code. im sure there is at least one person here who knows by heart how to solve your issue, but if you want assistance from other programmers who want to help, you need to give us some code to tinker with...

Comment: @Banana.  I think he was pretty clear as to what he wants to accomplish.

Comment: @DRD you didnt get my point.

Comment: are you restricted to css only? because its relatively easy to achieve using javascript

Comment: @Banana I would like to restrict myself to CSS if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

#### HTML

```
<body>
    <aside>Left</aside>
    <main>Right</main>
</body>
```

#### CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

main {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    background: cyan;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

aside {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    background: magenta;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the widths.

Comment: Widths are dynamic, not absolute.

Comment: @Keavon That's what I'm saying. It should work fine if you don't set a width.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I missed your word "without" in your comment. Let me give this a try.

Comment: The middle element pushes inside the left element, see http://jsfiddle.net/9UJnt/5/

Comment: @Keavon Ah crap didn't think of that... Hmm quite a tough problem really.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses absolute positioning and requires the left block's width to be explicitly set.  Essentially, absolute positioning takes the block out of the flow and to make sure that the left and right blocks do not overlap, the left margin is set on the right block that is the size of the left block's width.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4RqEr/. (Resize the preview window to see the effect).

HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
    <div>left</div>
    <div>Pushed to Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

.container {
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container > div:first-child,
.container > div:nth-child(2) {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #fA5858;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: 15px/1 Sans-Serif;
}

.container > div:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
}

.container > div:nth-child(2) {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #5882FA;
    margin: 0 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: only works if he knows the width of left elements, if its dynamic your solution wont work

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in the intro: "...and requires the left block's width to be explicitly set."

Comment: @Banana Thanks for reminding me to mention that. I have edited my question to mention that widths are unknown.

Comment: I think your best option is to use this solution, and just adjust the margin of the blue element using javascript after dom loads

Comment: You can actually get it done without JavaScript, but the only solution I could come up with is using flex-box and using extra markup.  Essentially, the left block is duplicated (in HTML) and situated as the last one (using HTML or `order`).  Then, you can use `justify-content: space-between` and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jdh2H/.